# Python error: unident does not match any outer identation level

Tags: python

i have a problem with my pygame code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

ANCHO_MAPA = 800
ALTO_MAPA = 600
pos_x = 0

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO_MAPA, ALTO_MAPA))
pygame.display.set_caption("Gercho")

tile = pygame.image.load('ima/0.png').convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    for x in range(ALTO_MAPA):
        screen.blit(tile, (1, x))


    pygame.display.flip()
```

and when i try it, i get this error. what's the problem?

Comment: Use four spaces consistently, no tabs. Make sure your editor does this automatically!

Comment: if you hit tab in one place and press the space bar 4 times in another spot, even though they look the same you are mixing identation

Comment: I have seen copying code from one place to another will cause this

Answer (score 1):

Do not mix tabs and spaces.

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():    # <- tabs
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    for x in range(ALTO_MAPA):          # <- spaces
        screen.blit(tile, (1, x))


    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: but i dont mix tabs and spaces!! where?